# How do I change the heading point of compass?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to make an app, which can get a random geo point (longitude and latitude) and point the compass's arrow to that point.
I made this code:

```
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Imagine a circle with +'s like surface. | is magnetic north, starting from x:0 to y: 90
    //PointX\Y is a random geo point, here by ints for test

    int MagneticNorthX = 0;
    int MagneticNorthY = 90;

    int pointX = 50;
    int pointY = 10;



    private void ToggleCompass()
    {
        if (Compass.Default.IsSupported)
        {
            if (!Compass.Default.IsMonitoring)
            {
                // Turn on compass
                Compass.Default.ReadingChanged += Compass_ReadingChanged;
                Compass.Default.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);
            }
            else
            {
                // Turn off compass
                Compass.Default.Stop();
                Compass.Default.ReadingChanged -= Compass_ReadingChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Compass_ReadingChanged(object sender, CompassChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update UI Label with compass state
        double res = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth));
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(res);
        this.text.Text = $"{e.Reading} + {this.arrow.Rotation}";
        this.arrow.RotateTo(value);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleCompass();
    }
}
```

Result: now my code is just showing where am I watching, but not heading to the test point. How can I change the heading of the compass?

Comment: you need to do the math to figure out what angle the test point is at